# Why Does W3schools Icons Not Animating

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have followed the instructions and even tried copy and pasting. (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_menu_icon_js), however the animation doesn't play out fully? the bars don't become the X and instead they reset halfway through the animation.

Any idea what might be causing this? I have included the code below.

```js
      function myFunction(x) {
        x.classList.toggle("change");
      }
```

```css
        .menu-container {
      display: inline-block;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
      width: 35px;
      height: 5px;
      background-color: #fff;
      margin: 6px 0;
      transition: 0.4s;
    }
    
    .change .bar1 {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
      transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
    }
    
    .change .bar2 {opacity: 0;}
    
    .change .bar3 {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
      transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
    }
```

```html
HTML

    <div class="menu-container" onClick="myFunction(this)">
                  <div class="bar1"></div>
                  <div class="bar2"></div>
                  <div class="bar3"></div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Your code is working fine for me. May be there is some other css or js getting applied on your site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update the `translate` for `.bar1` check snippet.

```
.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-8px, 8px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-8px, 8px);
}
```

```js
function myFunction(x) {
    x.classList.toggle("change");
  }
```

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-8px, 8px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-8px, 8px);
}

.change .bar2 {opacity: 0;}

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -7px);
}
```

```html
<p>Click on the Menu Icon to transform it to "X":</p>
<div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
  <div class="bar1"></div>
  <div class="bar2"></div>
  <div class="bar3"></div>
</div>
```